# SwiftyJSON and Alamofire data parsing in TableView (iOS, Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, phpmyadmin, swift4

When I run my project I am just able to get only `tableView` but datas are not fetched its blank. The struct `codable` and view controller codes were as follows. Please help me in viewing the datas in my `tableView` cells using `alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON`,

```
class Loads: Codable {
    let loads: [Load]
    init(loads: [Load]) {
        self.loads = loads
    }
}

class Load: Codable {
    let id: String
    let ad_title: String
    let ad_description:String
    let ad_price: String
    let ad_post_date: String
    let image1: String

    init(ad_title: String, ad_description: String, ad_price: String, ad_post_date: String, image1: String) {
        self.ad_title = ad_title
        self.ad_description = ad_description
        self.ad_price = ad_price
        self.ad_post_date = ad_post_date
        self.image1 = image1

    }
}
```

View Controller codes:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
var loads = [Load]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadJson()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection
        section: Int) -> Int {
        return loads.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
        IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LoadCell") as? LoadCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        cell.labelA.text = loads[indexPath.row].ad_title
        cell.labelB.text = loads[indexPath.row].ad_price
        cell.labelC.text = loads[indexPath.row].ad_description
        cell.labelD.text = loads[indexPath.row].ad_post_date
        if let imageURL = URL(string: loads[indexPath.row].image1) {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                if let data = data {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.loadImage.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cell    
    }

    func downloadJson(){
        Alamofire.request("https://alot.ae/api/classifiedcomputerlaptop.php").responseJSON { response in

            if let value = response.result.value {

                let json = JSON(value)

                //Printing strings from a JSON Dictionary
                print(json[0]["ad_title"].stringValue)
                print(json[0]["ad_price"].stringValue)
                print(json[0]["ad_description"].stringValue)
                print(json[0]["ad_post_date"].stringValue)
                print(json[0]["image1"].stringValue)
            }
          self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
 }
```

I am using xcode9, swift 4.

Comment: no need of this `class Loads: Codable {`

Answer (score 1):

> datas are not fetched its blank

Your code does not seem to update `var loads` by downloaded data, that is why you just get blank table view. So, you need to assign fetched data to `var loads`.

Here is sample:

```
Alamofire.request("https://alot.ae/api/classifiedcomputerlaptop.php").responseJSON { response in 
    // you should assign response data into var loads here 
    if let data = response.data {
            do {
                self.loads = try JSONDecoder().decode([Load].self, from: data)
            } catch {
                // exception
            }
    }
}
```

And after that, `self.tableView.reloadData()`.

PS: Of course I don't know your response JSON format and your source code overall, so it might not be a directory answer to your question, but I hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the url looks faulty to me. `https` is typed twice, please remove once in below line.

Change this :

```
Alamofire.request("https:https://alot.ae/api/classifiedcomputerlaptop.php").responseJSON
```

to :

```
Alamofire.request("https://alot.ae/api/classifiedcomputerlaptop.php").responseJSON
```

Comment: i mistyped URL, but with correct https also when i runtime same problem.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your...

> struct codable

... is not a struct at all, it is a class. change that to an actual struct.

Second, you start downloading before your delegate and datasource are set to the tableview.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate   = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    downloadJson()
}
```

Thirdly, you are using Alamofire for a simple GET request, but you ignore the fact of asyncronous loading of images for a cell, which you do with `Data`. I'd suggest to use [AlamoFireImageDownloader](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) or remote AlamoFire all together. Using [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) is just as easy:

```
private func request(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping ((Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    task.resume()
}
```

Fourth, I don't believe you need the `loads` codable.

Just an extra reminder, depending on the amount of `Load`s you'll have in your table, you will get problems with the loading of your images. The closures are not guaranteed to finish in order, but when they do they will update the cell regardless to whether the cell is already reused for another `Load` or not. Just FYI.